Is it possible to update a field with the result of mysql concat and join?
Is it possible to update a field with the result of mysql concat and join?
select CONCAT_WS(' - ', r.spare, r.assembly, r.model) 
reemplazos from TblPartes p 
left join TblReemplazos r 
on p.codigo1 = r.Option where p.codigo1 = 'V4-VS07-040'

I get 3 rows of results with multiple columns.



reemplazos




005050748 - 005050148 - 005050749


005050149 - 005050552- 005050953


005052065 - 005052064



but if I use update, the result of the update its only the first row.








005050748 - 005050148 - 005050749



update TblPartes As p 
left JOIN TblReemplazos As r 
On p.codigo1 = r.Option 
Set p.stock_reemp = 
CONCAT_WS(' - ', r.spare, r.assembly, r.model)

How can make the update using the result of the first select?
(concat all rows)
I need something like this
update TblPartes As p 
left JOIN TblReemplazos As r 
On p.codigo1 = r.Option 
Set p.stock_reemp = select CONCAT_WS(' - ', r.spare, r.assembly, r.model) 
reemplazos from TblPartes p 
left join TblReemplazos r 
on p.codigo1 = r.Option

TblReemplazos



id
option
spare
assembly
model




1
V4-VS07-040
005050748
005050148
005050749


2
V4-VS07-040
005050149
005050552
005050953


3
V4-VS07-040
005052065
005052064



4
V8-VS08-080
8811uu33
8811uu44
8811uu55



TblPartes



id
codigo1
stock_reemp




1
V4-VS07-040



2
V8-VS08-080




TblPartes(desired result)



id
codigo1
stock_reemp




1
V4-VS07-040
005050748 -  005050148 - 005050749 - 005050149 -005050552 -005050953 - 005052065 - 005052064


2
V8-VS08-080
8811uu33 - 8811uu44 - 8811uu55



Thanks.

Please add the original data, not just the results, so I can try to run the query myself.

GROUP BY without any aggregation functions is usually a mistake. Unless you've disabled the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode, or option is the primary key, your original query should have gotten an error.

If you're only getting one row updated, it means that none of the other rows have a matching codigo1 = option

The original query was just an example of what I was trying to do. It is not a functional query.

What I want is to Update the TblPartes.stock_reemp Field With the Result of the CONCAT_WS
The relationship makes it
TblPartes.codigo1 with TblReemplazos.option

I have updated the original post again.

Why do you think you need TWO left joins of the same thing?

If you want to use a subquery as a value, you have to put it in parentheses. But the correlated subquery should produce the same result as a join,.

Your latest update still doesn't show the original contents of the two tables. And your output doesn't show the value of the tblPartes.codigo1.

Sorry, I'm new to the site. I have reflected example of the tables and the desired result

You need to use GROUP_CONCAT() to combine the values from multiple rows. This means you need to join with a subquery that uses GROUP_CONCAT().
Also, option shouldn't be in the CONCAT_WS().
update TblPartes AS p
left join (
    SELECT `option`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(" - ", spare, assembly, model) SEPARATOR ' - ') AS stock_reemp
    FROM TblReemplazos
    GROUP BY `option`
) AS r on p.codigo1 = r.`option`
set p.stock_reemp = r.stock_reemp;

DEMO

I've updated the answer now that you showed that it needs to use GROUP_CONCAT().

Magnificent. So easy for you, and it took me all day.
I really appreciate the time you gave me.

So there was a reason why you were using GROUP BY in the original query!

Yes, the only thing I don't know how to do now is how to avoid repeated registrations in the CONCAT_WS fields(" ", option, assembly, model)
it's possible? If not it does not matter.

You mean you're getting duplicates? You can use GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(...))

I tried that before, but it didn't work. I think it's because sometimes there are repeated fields in different places at the same time.

I'm not really sure what kind of repeated registrations you're referring to. If spare is repeated with different assembly or model, is it really a repetition?

You can ask a new question where you show sample data that has the duplicates you want to avoid, and the expected result.

thanks again Barmar, i made a new question.

I can't find it. Did you delete it?
